# Supplied connections must be of type AstDbConnectionNode

Tags: ssis, biml

I have been working on a simple BIML solution to start learning how to use it.  I keep getting an error message:

> Supplied connections must be of type AstDbConnectionNode for this method.
>   at Varigence.Biml.Extensions.ExternalDataAccess.GetDatabaseSchema in :line 0

I've been searching and trying different solutions and have not found an answer yet.  So, I'm turning to everyone here.  I need another set of eyes on this so I can figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My first BIML file has my connection setup to World Wide Importers on my local box.

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">

<#@ template language = "C#" tier="0" #>

<Connections>
<OleDbConnection
    Name="src" 
    ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQL16;Initial Catalog=WorldWideImporters;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
    CreateInProject = "true">
</OleDbConnection>
</Connections>

<Databases>
    <Database Name="src" ConnectionName = "src" />
</Databases>
```

Second BIML file is what is throwing the error

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">

<#@ template language = "C#" tier = "1" #>
<#@ import namespace="Varigence.Biml.CoreLowerer.SchemaManagement" #>

<# var srcDB = RootNode.OleDbConnections["src"]; #>
<# var WWIdb = srcDB.GetDatabaseSchema(ImportOptions.ExcludeViews); #>

<Packages>
    <# foreach (var table in WWIdb.TableNodes) { #>
    <Package Name="<#=table.Schema#>_<#=table.Name#>"     ConstraintMode="Linear">
        <Tasks>
            <Dataflow Name="DF Copy <#=table.Name#>">
            </Dataflow>
        </Tasks>
    </Package>
    <# } #>
</Packages>
</Biml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That, misleading, error surfaces from the call to `GetDatabaseSchema` I say it's misleading because the root problem is that srcDB is null. See for yourself by using this code in your second Biml file.

```
<#@ import namespace="System.Windows.Forms" #>
<#@ assembly name= "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Windows.Forms.dll" #>
<# var srcDB = RootNode.OleDbConnections["ConnectionDoesNotExist"]; #>
<#
    if (srcDB == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("It's null");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("It's not null - {0}", srcDB.Name);
    }
#>
```

### Root problem

You are access an object in the connections collection that doesn't exist - probably because while you have your tiering correct, you need to "include" all the files when you build.

### How do you resolve this?

If you're using [BimlExpress](http://www.varigence.com/BimlExpress/) or [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) then you simply need to select both file1.biml and file2.biml in the solution menu and right click to generate package.

If you are using [Mist/BimlStudio](http://www.varigence.com/BimlStudio/), then I would just right click on file1.biml and change that to Convert to Live BimlScript.

Comment: Also led to another issue of the SQL Native Client not working correctly since I only had SQL 2016 installed.  Switched to Provider=SQLOLEDB and everything started working.  Thanks!